Is Closed Cell or Open Cell foam better for sound reduction?
My bedroom faces directly towards a noisy highway. I'm trying to figure out how to reduce some of the traffic noise, and am thinking about spray foaming the walls. Is it better to use open cell or closed cell spray foam for noise reduction?
I have read that closed cell foam might actually increase the noise, because it adds rigidity to the wall, and creates a more effective bridge for transmitting noise. Is this actually true? Will CC foam actually make the problem worse? Or is it just less effective than open cell in terms of noise reduction?
More detail on what I'm planning to do: Remove the drywall and existing insulation, air seal with 1/2" of foam, then add Rockwool insulation. I'm not planning to fill the entire cavity with spray foam.

I'm pretty sure you need to use CC foam in a flash-and-batt for moisture/air control reasons...

FWIW, blown-in fiber insulation did reduce sound coming through my walls, at least in the higher frequency ranges. Low frequency noise gets coupled through the framing; see past answers tagged noise-reduction.
